# How to change two sum to two for loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sum, outer-join

**EDITED:**

I have a vector named `y` which has `n` numerical elements and a matrix `n*n` named `w` where its elements are numbers.

```
y<-c(312,218,259,76,263) 

> w
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0    0    1
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    1    0    0
```

I want to use the below formula for the above data:
[image]
I have written the following codes in R using functions `outer` and `sum`:

```
dy<-y-mean(y)
M<-outer(dy,dy,"*")
a<-sum(w*M)
s0<-sum(w)
n<-length(y)
v<-n/sum(dy^2)
L<-v*a/s0
```

The output of `L` is `-0.1873`

Now, I want to change my above codes to write it with two `for` loops (without using `outer` and `sum`). Indeed, I want to make the formula using two `for` loops instead of using `outer` and `sum` and find again `L` as `-0.1873`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First compute all numerators and denominators of this formula, then compute I from them.

This should do the trick:

```
##Fraction: n1/d1 * n2/d2

d1 = 0
n1 = n
d2 = 0
n2 = 0
my = mean(y)
for(i in 1:n){
  d1 = d1 + (my-y[i])**2
  for(j in 1:n){
    n2 = n2+w[i,j]*(y[i]-my)*(y[j]-my)
    d2 = d2+w[i,j]
  }
}

I = n1/d1 * n2/d2
```

Comment: Are you sure about `n2` and `d2` in your code? Because when I use your code for my data the output of `n2`, `d2`, and `I` will be `NA`. @MartinWettstein

Comment: I added more data to my question and edited it in the above. Please look at it again. @MartinWettstein

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. w_ij is `w[i,j]` in R, not `w[i][j]`, as I wrote in the answer. I corrected it. Now, it works.